# How to access element node in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

How do I access the `li` element in the click handler to add a class when it is clicked?

```
const Type = React.createClass({
  clickHandler: function () {
    ...
  },
  render () {
    const classType = `cell type type-${this.props.name}`
    return (
      <li
      onClick={this.clickHandler}
      className={classType}
      >
      {this.props.name}
      </li>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: I am not familiar with react itself but almost all frameworks that have event wrappers pass a reference in the clickHandler argument to the scope/viewModel/this of the action handler and the second param is often the dom node itself.  Have you put a break in the clickHandler to look at arguments list?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation

Answer (score 1):

The most "React-ful" way to do this would be to store the `li` class name or status in component state (or Redux I guess if that's your thing) and modify it via the click handler.

```
const Type = React.createClass({
  clickHandler: function () {
    this.setState({wasClicked: true});
  },
  render () {
    const classType = `cell type type-${this.props.name}` + (this.state.wasClicked ? " some-new-class-name" : " ")
    return (
      <li
      onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}
      className={classType}
      >
      {this.props.name}
      </li>
    )
  }
})
```

Note that you have to bind the "this" scope to clickHandler (to get access to this.setState) if you're using ES6.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get any of the data of the `li` you could just add in the call to the event function when adding the element. Say you want to access `classType` in onClick:

```
const Type = React.createClass({
  clickHandler: function (classType) {
    /* Do something with the li classType */
  },
  render () {
    const classType = `cell type type-${this.props.name}`
    return (
      <li
      onClick={() => this.clickHandler(classType)}
      className={classType}
      >
      {this.props.name}
      </li>
    )
  }
})
```